# PHP Document Root

Tags: php

I have a header which i want to include into many other php files in different directory.  In order for all the navigation to work, I have tried using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to get the root directory of the project.  Only issue is that the "document" root is the root of wherever the original request is from (not always the root directory of the project but rather the file.  **I always want it to be the top level directory** so that the links may stay the same.  How might I do this?

As an example if I am in the project's root it works fine

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$root .= "index.php";
```

result string is /path/to/project/dir/index.php

however if i'm in a sub directory it doesn't

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$root .= "html/page.php";
```

result string is /path/to/page.php/file/html/page.php

whereas I want the result /path/to/project/dir/html/page.php

Answer (score 0):

if you call [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) it should give you the path

Comment: wouldn't this get the current directory the php script is running in?  not the root?

Comment: for example getcwd('/path/to/rootdir');  gives /path/to/rootdir  however if php is executing in a sub directory such as html it return /path/to/rootdir/home whereas I just want it to give /path/to/rootdir

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to accomplish this is actually to just use the "root" of the server.  For example I was running a LAMP stack and the root directory as defined in the httpd.conf file was `/var/www/html`  so when a link starts with `/` it is the root directory of the application.

Answer (score -2):

use following environment variable to get root path

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

or you can use to get full path

```
'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
```

try to echo this